# MariaDB LDAP PAM Authentication

Tags: ldap, mariadb, pam

I have an Active Directory and a MariaDB server in my local test environment. Now I want to make it possible to log in with the AD user under MariaDB.

I have already looked at some tutorials and here pretty much every topic about it.

My /etc/nslc.conf:

```
    uid nslcd
    gid nslcd
    uri ldap://172.29.210.219/
    base dc=saptest,dc=local
    ldap_version 3
    binddn CN=bind,CN=Users,DC=SAPTEST,DC=LOCAL
    bindpw supersecurepassword
    ssl off
    filter passwd (objectClass=user)
    map passwd uid sAMAccountName
```

My /etc/pam.d/mariadb

```
auth sufficient pam_ldap.so
account sufficient pam_ldap.so
```

My steps in MariaDB

```
INSTALL SONAME 'auth_pam';
CREATE USER 'admin'@'%' IDENTIFIED VIA pam USING 'mariadb';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'admin'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
EXIT;
```

When I do "mysql -u admin -p" I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found that on my MariaDB instance 10.5.12 on SLES15SP3, the config file in pam.d has to be called 'mysql' and that the 'USING' option at the end of the user create statement does not work.

https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-26876

```
CREATE USER 'admin'@'%' IDENTIFIED VIA pam;
```

/etc/pam.d/mysql

```
auth required pam_ldap.so
auth required pam_warn.so
account required pam_ldap.so
account required pam_warn.so
```

pam_warn will spit out log messages to syslog (in my case Journal)
https://www.docs4dev.com/docs/en/linux-pam/1.1.2/reference/sag-pam_warn.html

The ldap configuration has to be in /etc/ldap.conf:

```
base dc=[redacted]
binddn cn=[redacted]
bindpw [redacted]
uri ldap://[redacted]:389
pam_login_attribute sAMAccountName
pam_filter objectclass=User
```